# How can I check whether the data already exists in combobox list?

Tags: vba

How can I check if the data from `cmbTypeYacht.text` already exists in `cmbTypeYacht.list`?

Here's what I've got:

```
Dim TypeYacht As String 'Type of yacht input

TypeYacht = cmbTypeYacht.Text

If TypeYacht = ("cmbTypeYacht list") Then
    MsgBox "Type of Yacht is already on the list", vbExclamation, "Yacht Chantering"
Else
    cmbTypeYacht.AddItem cmbTypeYacht.Text

    With cmbTypeYacht
        .Text = ""
        .SetFocus
    End With
End If
```

sorry about the tag im not quite sure which is it but im using Microsoft Visual Basic app.

Comment: Well, which is it, VB.NET or VBScript? Or VBA? I’m going to assume VB.NET, but you don’t have parentheses…

Comment: From your code it seems that cmbTypeYacht.Text in this case is the same as cmbTypeYacht.Value. Simply eliminate the TypeYacht String variable and use: If cmbTypeYacht.ListIndex >= 0 Then 'Type of Yacht is on the list ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ComboBox` class has a `FindStringExact()` method that will do the trick for you, like this:

```
Dim resultIndex As Integer = -1

resultIndex = cmbTypeYacht.FindStringExact(cmbTypeYacht.Text)

If resultIndex > -1 Then
    ' Found text, do something here
    MessageBox.Show("Found It")
Else
    ' Did not find text, do something here
    MessageBox.Show("Did Not Find It")
End If
```

You can also just loop through the list as well, like this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To cmbTypeYacht.Items.Count - 1
    If cmbTypeYacht.Items.Contains(cmbTypeYacht.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Found It")
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks karl,
im just curious, if there's any other ways beside's using the class FindStringExact()?

Comment: loop through the list?

Comment: @user2869223 - see `UPDATE:` in my answer.

Comment: @sam092 & Karl Anderson thanks for the help and tips. somehow i got it loop through the list using do until loop :)

Comment: @blackmaler - great, glad you got your code working. If you feel my answer helped you, then feel free to accept the answer. Also, when you  have enough reputation, also feel free to up-vote the answer. :-)

Comment: @KarlAnderson sry im new on the block :)

Comment: It is much easier to simply use the ListIndex property, as stated in SM177Y's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working in Excel 2013 and there is no FindStringExact or .Items.Contains so, neither of those are valid. There is also no need to iterate the list. It is very simple actually. Given a userform "MyUserForm" and a combobox "MyComboBox",

```
If MyUserForm.MyComboBox.ListIndex >= 0 Then
    MsgBox "Item is in the list"
Else
    MsgBox "Item is NOT in the list"
End If
```

Explanation: If selected item is not in the list, .ListIndex returns -1.

Comment: Reduce the code using  `if MyComboBox.ListIndex >= 0 Then`

Comment: Reducing like that could cause problems as it is inaccurate. If you had a combobox with the same name on separate sheets, then it would become ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah, that's easy enough. Best answer for me. It would be different if the question involved checking for a value in a different control, but since the only affected control is the cmbTypeYacht combobox, this is all it needs.

Answer (score 2):

The combobox in vba has a property called MatchFound. It will return true if the value you inputted in the combobox (`ComboBox.Value`) existed before.

Put below code in the update event of the combobox for trial

```
Private Sub ComboBox_AfterUpdate()
If ComboBox.MatchFound = True then
    Msgbox "Value exist"
End If
End Sub
```

Check it out:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/combobox-matchfound-property-outlook-forms-script

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate through combobox.items. Items.Contains will already iterate through the list for you.

Simply use:

```
If cmbTypeYacht.Items.Contains(cmbTypeYacht.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Found It")
    Exit For
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching: VBA check whether the data already exists in combobox list?
but vba doesnt have the properties above.

```
Sub TestString() 
    Dim myString As String 
    Dim i As Long 
    Dim strFound As Boolean 


     'Just for test purposes
    myString = "Apple" 


    strFound = False 
    With Me.ComboBox1 
         'Loop through combobox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 
            If .List(i) = myString Then 
                strFound = True 
                Exit For 
            End If 
        Next i 
         'Check if we should add item
        If Not strFound Then .AddItem (myString) 
    End With 
End Sub
```

This was found after a lot of searching at http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=187763
and actually works