# How to loop through a combo box in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an Active X Control Combo Box in my excel sheet which I have named simply as "ComboBox". Now I have a function that populates this like so:

```
With ComboBox
    .AddItem("Something")
```

I would like to be able to loop through the items in a combo box and check whether an item already exists before adding into it. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308611/how-can-i-check-whether-the-data-already-exists-in-combobox-list) question that was posted a few years ago but I cannot for the life of me able to do what they say. First, the FindStringExact method doesn't exist for this object. Nor does the property "Items" exist either. I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why it doesn't exist. Am I doing something wrong? Or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: I would start by at least not naming it `ComboBox` and instead name it something like `ComboBox1` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @braX Okay it's actually not named "ComboBox", it's named something else. I just wrote that for simplicity sake for the question

Answer (score 0):

### Read Combo Box

- In the sheet module of the worksheet containing the combo box use:

```vb
Sub LoopCombo()
    
    With ComboBox1
        
        ' Populate, e.g.:
        .List = Array(3, 2, 5)
    
        ' For Each...Next
        Dim Item As Variant
        For Each Item In .List
            Debug.Print Item
        Next Item
        
        ' For...Next
        Dim n As Long
        For n = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            Debug.Print n, .List(n)
        Next n
    
    End With

End Sub
```